# In Qt, how to make a slider move event fire when using the arrow keys?

Tags: qt

I have a slider:

```
QSlider *mySlider;
```

And I have a slot wired to it:

```
void on_mySlider_sliderMoved(int position);
```

It's wired in setupUI when this is called:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
```

When I slide the slider with the **mouse**, this slot fires correctly and all is well. However, if I click it once with the mouse to "select" it and then use the **arrows on the keyboard**, I see the slider moving, but the slot never fires.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QAbstractSlider::sliderMoved`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#sliderMoved) signal is emitted when you drag the slider. From the docs: *This signal is emitted when sliderDown is true and the slider moves. This usually happens when the user is dragging the slider.*

Use [`QAbstractSlider::valueChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) signal if you want to know every time the value of the slider is changed.